# Creating Attendance query for 4 Consecutive absence per student

Tags: sql

I am creating an attendance query. that checks for four Consecutive absences per student and I am using the below query, however the query never resets absentrun at a new student.

set @absentRun = 0;

SELECT StudentID, name,grade,phone,date,status,
CASE absenceID
WHEN 1
THEN CASE WHEN @absentRun= 4 THEN @absentRun:= 1 ELSE @absentRun := @absentRun + 1 END
WHEN 2
THEN @absentRun := 0
END AS Absent
FROM Attendance group by date,name

for example if studentID is 1 and the next record student ID is 2 I would like the absent count to reset like the table below

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>StudentID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Grade</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>AbsenceID</th>
    <th>AbsentCount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Peter</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>57575r</td>
  <td>09/12/2021</td>
  <td>Absent</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Pedro</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>444</td>
  <td>09/12/2021</td>
  <td>absent</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>1</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Pedro</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>444</td>
  <td>09/12/2021</td>
  <td>absent</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Pedro</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>444</td>
  <td>09/12/2021</td>
  <td>absent</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   

</table>
```

Please let me know if there is any further information needed.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: MySql <> SQL Server - i removed the conflicting tags, please add back the tag for the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get this to work although it is not perfect but I am posting it here hopefully it helps someone and hope if someone found a more efficient solution to let me know.

1. I created a view with all the fields and added sequence using the below select statement:
   select Name, date_absent, Attendance status, stu_id,AbsenceReasonID,row_number() over ( partition by StudentID order by Date) AS seqnum
2. used nested select sql statement to count absence through case conditions.
   a) absencereasonID = 1 that if status is present set the counter to zero (eliminate any present from the report)
   b) if absencereasonid =2 (absent) **AND** sequence number less or equal 2 and if so check if the counter not equal zero then counter (@absentrun) = seqnum, else counter is equal one
   c) if absencereasoin id = 2 (absent) **AND** sequence number is greater than 2 then if counter is = 4 (i am looking for four absences then reset the counter to 1) else add one to counter absence run

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT name,grade,phone,date,status, absencereasonID, seqnum, CASE
WHEN AbsenceReasonID = 1 THEN @absentRun := 0
WHEN AbsenceReasonID = 2 AND seqnum <= 2 THEN CASE WHEN @absentRun != 0 THEN @absentRun := seqnum ELSE @absentRun := 1 END
WHEN AbsenceReasonID = 2 AND seqnum > 2 THEN CASE WHEN @absentRun = 4 THEN @absentRun := 1 ELSE @absentRun := @absentRun + 1 END

END AS Present

FROM Attend_seqnum )e WHERE Present >= 4 AND date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() ORDER BY date

Hope that helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS-SQL Server an outer apply would work here.

I have not used variable the way you are using them before. Where I would use them would be collecting an aggregate value from a table such as a max date.

Generally for this type of query I would leverage sub queries or window functions to calculate instead.

```
select 
  a.studentid, 
  a.studentname, 
  a.phonenumber, 
  a.attendance_date, 
  a.absense_flag, 
  CASE 
    WHEN SUM( a2.absence_flag ) >= 4 THEN  1 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS fourday_absence_flag 
from attendance a
  OUTER APPLY  
  (
    SELECT TOP 4 
      absence_flag
    FROM attendance a2
    WHERE 
      a2.studentid = a.studentid 
      a2.attendance_date <= a.attendance_date 
    ORDER BY attendance_date DESC 
  ) a2
 GROUP BY 
    a.studentid, 
    a.studentname, 
    a.phonenumber, 
    a.attendance_date, 
    a.absense_flag
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, however when I tried to use the query I got the below error. 

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 4 AbsenceReasonID FROM attend...' at line 11

Comment: Got it - yea outer apply is not supported in all dbs.  Added another answer from looking through mariadb docs. Also saw that mysql did support some aggregate queries leveraging variables similar to how you approached this.  Do not have experience with this method . Seems like it should be feasible though.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at mariadb docs ( havnt used maria and dont have an environment to test).

Seems this may work for a rolling aggregate.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-frames/

```
SELECT 
   studentid, 
   name, 
   grade, 
   phone, 
   date, 
   status, 
   sum (absenceID) OVER (ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_absence 
  FROM Attendance
```